# How do I select datetime range in input field from canvas in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using Chart.js@4.2.1 and chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0. I need to have two input fields on the top of canvas. When I touchmove the input field on complete canvas on x axis then it should show the x- time scale value on inputs. And fill a different color between the two input fields on the canvas.

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproducible sample? Thinking loud, a possible solution is to leverage on 'segment' options but it works for line controller only.

Comment: @user2057925 Thankyou for reply. I am using line chart. Also want that does not matter if data is present  or not in the the the given time. For example if i have see last 6 hours data and may possible that data is  not available but then also when moving the input filled then it should show all the datetime  x axis ticks when moving. I used this but it show only first tick in troughout canvas. export function MouseHandler(chart, mousemove) { const {scales: { x, y } } = chart;  console.log(x.ticks[0].label)}myChart.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {MouseHandler(myChart, e); })

Comment: If I have understood your use case, you could use chartjs-plugin-zoom. But if you want only highight the "selected" data, you could use chatjs-plugin-annotation add a box which is highlighting the selected area.

Comment: @user2057925 Thankyou for suggesting chatjs-plugin-annotation. I can work further